# Migrated from Meteor 1.2 to Meteor 1.8 resulted in extremely slow performance

Tags: meteor

I just migrated my application from Meteor 1.2 to Meteor 1.8 (Angularjs).

My application is extremely slow, I am fetching 20 records per page, and it loads like half of the records and then it gets stuck.
After that I have to kill my application, and relaunch, it works fine for 5 or 10m minutes max and gets slower again.
There is no error on the server terminal or browser console, what could be the issue here?
Is there any way to debug this? So that I can know if there is some issue with my queries or code that is causing this issue after migration?
For the record I am still using Angular 1 on client, since I have a huge web application.

Here is the version of my node version installed on system

```
nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

I am using old version of nodejs, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very old version of nodejs, but if you always use `meteor npm install` instead of just plain `npm install` then it should be ok.

I presume you have done a `meteor reset` to clear out any old meteor builds, and a `rm -rf node_modules` to clear out any old npm packages?

It would also be worth doing a `npm cache reset -f` to clear out the npm cache.

Comment: I will clear out the packages, but I dont think so that node modules are the issue here. I need to debug my app to find out what is making my app that slow, is there any way to debug that? may be I need to optimize some of my queries or subscriptions, but I need to know which one first.

Comment: @StormTrooper without looking at your code, I don't know what else to suggest. You can look at the CPU on your computer, to see if it the server or the client that's chewing up the CPU. You can attach the debugger to either process, some guidance is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/meteor - I have had better success doing an `attach` rather than a `launch` (I can share configs if you need). I could also have a quick look if you can share your repo with me.

Comment: Right i will try to share my repo with you. But yeah when the app is going down, the system node is using 105%   of cpu usage.

Comment: my github id is mikkelking

Comment: I am getting error on meteor server terminal: "Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit" Getting while using my admin page where I show the list of all users and when I visit last page. i have total 41268 users. I am showing 20 users per page which are controlled by subscription. I added an index on cDate.timeStamp: -1, it is solved now but I have other filters too, like profile completion percentage asc or desc. So what should I do not? how should I add index for both asc and desc?

Comment: One index will suffice for either ascending or descending sorts. Sounds like you had a breakthrough!

Comment: Currently my app is running fine and smooth, but after few hours it goes down for 2 or 3 minutes and after that it goes up. And at that time node uses 105% or plus of CPU. I assume there is something which ever runs, it downs my server.

Comment: Is there a timed job that runs, or is it just gradually running out of memory?

Comment: its random, no specific time

Comment: I have used so many nested Meteor.settimeout() and build logic inside each Meteor.settimeout(), each Meteor.settimeout() decide the delay time for child one, could that be slowing down my server?

Comment: That could be a source of problem. I would lean towards having a single cron entry (I think I use node-cron) which fires every 5 minutes, and looks for things to do. If there is nothing, it's not an expensive invocation. You can create a 'timerQueue` collection in your database. Each entry has a status value, starting at 0, meaning it needs to be done. a status value of 1 means it was completed, and a value of 2 means it failed (You can store an error message too).